# How to use document to rewrite a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
document.getElementById("txtOutput").value = result;
```

instead of using `.value=result`, can I write something else to say, rewrite to a specific div or paragraph?

Comment: I did not catch your question?

Comment: There are a bajillion duplicates of this, as well as an almost uncountable number of resources elsewhere on the internet. Do some basic research next time, for everyone's sake :) Voting to close as dup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write something (including html-formatations) you can use innerHTML orherwise if you need only the text use innerText:

**innerHTML**

```
document.getElementById("txtOutput").innerHTML = result
```

**innerText**

```
document.getElementById("txtOutput").innerText = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Look at this simple [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8yUW/) for an example.

HTML:

```
<div id="me">
    <span>old stuff</span>
</div>
```

Script

```
document.getElementById('me').innerHTML = "new stuff";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use innerHTML:

```
 document.getElementById("txtOutput").innerHTML = 'some content';
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is a property not a function. You should be using `=` instead.

Comment: Just like that ! ... and we'll keep wondering how our posts don't end up being useful. 8-|